# Google Compute Engine: VM creation just spins and spins…

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I created a VM in the Compute Engine and it's been going through the creation step for over half an hour (the circle next to it just spins and spins). I see no way to stop it and there appears to be no progress. How do I find out what's going on, or kill it?

Answer (score 0):

Google's smarter than I thought: after several hours, Google killed the half-existent node on its own.